# Ubuntu one client for MeeGo

Tags: ubuntu-one, client, meego, nokia

I am using Ubuntu One Clients on different platforms and it's all working very well, as there are Win 7 PCs and ubuntu 11.10, where it is integated already.
Now i'm trying to add my mobile, which i thought would not be a problem, as my mobile, a nokia N9, runs on MeeGo, linux in fact. 
Could there be a chance to get a client for MeeGo? Android and iOS are existing, so could it be a hard challenge?
I also thougt about switching to dropbox, because clients for Windows, Ubuntu and MeeGo are available at dropbox, but as a linux-fan i would of course wait for a ubuntu One-Solution.
all i could find was a project at google, you can find here:
http://code.google.com/p/meego-u1/
unfortunately i am ony a user not a developer.

Greetins

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for something like that app: "Ubi: An unofficial Ubuntu One app for Maemo 5 and other Qt-enabled platforms"

Link: http://ubi.garage.maemo.org/

Answer (score 1):

You may find http://kryogenix.org/code/u1fn9/ useful; it's a first release of Ubuntu One Files for the N9.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a look on the Meego forums and in particular here:

[Meego handset forums](http://forum.meego.com/forumdisplay.php?f=7)

Apologies if you have done this already.

You can also check in the dev mailing lists or meego IRC for meego which I am sure which the details used to be found here:

[Meego community guide](https://meego.com/community)